# O(n) algorithm for the connected components at most n/2 problem

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I'm given a problem statement which states
"There always exists a vertex from a tree G such that the remaining connected components have size at most |V(G)|/2".

I'm trying to formulate an efficient algorithm for this and am not sure where to start.
I'd love some hints and can take it from there. Thanks.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: The first step is proving that such a vertex always exists. Perhaps the proof will give you some ideas.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742440/you-can-always-delete-a-vertex-from-a-tree-g-such-that-the-remaining-connected